Subgroup fixing a subset of $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$
Consider the multiplicative cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$, where $p\geq 7$ is an odd prime. Let $S_m=\{\pm 1(mod~p),\pm 2(mod~p),\ldots,\pm m(mod~p)\}$ where $2\leq m \leq \frac{p-3}{2}$. Define $Fix(S_m)=\{a \in \mathbb{Z}^*_p:aS_m=S_m\}$. (the action is left multiplication). It is easy to see that $Fix(S_m)$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ and $\pm 1(mod~p) \in Fix(S_m)$.
I am trying to prove that $\forall m \in [2,\frac{p-3}{2}]$, $Fix(S_m)=\{\pm 1(mod~p)\}$.
Any help will be appreciated.
(Note that if $m=\frac{p-1}{2}$, then $Fix(S_m)=\mathbb{Z}^*_p$. )
So far, I have been able to prove:

$Fix(S_m)\subseteq S_m \subset \mathbb{Z}^*_p$.
If $m<\frac{p}{3}$, then $Fix(S_m)=\{\pm 1(mod~p)\}$.
If $k \in \{1,2,3,\ldots,m\}$ and $k \in Fix(S_m)$, then $k$ must be odd.


After computing some examples, I believe this problem is related to the distribution of prime numbers. Where does the problem come from?

The problem comes from a question on algebraic degree of circulant graphs, i.e., Cayley graphs on $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Consider the sum of squares
$$
A=\sum_{j\in S_m}j^2=2\sum_{j=1}^m j^2=\frac13m(m+1)(2m+1).
$$
If $a\in Fix(S_m)$, then $aS_m=S_m$, and
$$
a^2A\equiv\sum_{j\in S_m}a^2j^2\equiv\sum_{j\in S_m}(aj)^2\equiv\sum_{\ell\in S_m}\ell^2\equiv A
$$
This means that $(a^2-1)A$ must be divisible by $p$.
Clearly $A$ can be divisible by $p$ only if one of the factors $m$, $m+1$,
$2m+1$ is. But all those cases are ruled out by $m\le(p-3)/2$.
The conclusion is thus that $a^2-1$ must be divisible by $p$.

I managed to simplify my first proof to bare essentials, so I think that a rewrite is ok :-)

All hail the power of averaging over a group!

Thanks for this nice and elegant proof.

Incredibly elegant!
